# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException From ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, events, nullpointerexception, awt

I am working on a class assignment tonight and I have most of the program written however I have a stubborn bit of code that will not work no matter how I have tweaked it.  I may not have the exact understanding of how the specific object works though.

So what is going on is that I have an ArrayList of objects that I am iterating through, getting a specific variable from, and saving into a new ArrayList since the receiving object has to be able to change as needed.

However when I try to return the second ArrayList Eclipse tells me the type is not right.  I tried using its suggestion of

```
return (String[]) iNames.toArray();
```

but that causes the error mentioned in the title.  I also tried just passing it back as an object array but same thing happens when the combobox is created.

Here is my code, what you want to look at are the following methods:

guiCInventory in MenuOperations where the ComboBox is created
Object[] getINames() in Operations

You may also want to look at addSItem to see how I am creating the ArrayList of TableValues that I am pulling the information from to try and populate the ComboBox with.

prg421_w2_IA:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class prg421_w2_IA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUI mMenu = new GUI();

    //mMenu.setBounds(100, 100, 537, 223);
    //mMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //mMenu.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

GUI

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{   
public GUI()
{       
    setBounds(100, 100, 537, 223);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    mMenu = this;       
    setVisible(true);

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Retail Operations Application V1.0");
    lblTitle.setBounds(10, 0, 169, 14);
    add(lblTitle);

    btnAIS = new JButton("Add Item to Store",null);
    btnAIS.setBounds(392, 31, 119, 23);
    add(btnAIS);

    btnAIC = new JButton("Add Item to Customer Cart",null);
    btnAIC.setBounds(348, 65, 163, 23);
    mMenu.getContentPane().add(btnAIC);

    btnSCC = new JButton("Show Customer Cart",null);
    btnSCC.setBounds(380, 99, 131, 23);
    mMenu.getContentPane().add(btnSCC);

    btnEProgram = new JButton("Exit Program",null);
    btnEProgram.setBounds(418, 133, 93, 23);
    mMenu.getContentPane().add(btnEProgram);

    sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setBounds(21, 36, 317, 127);
    mMenu.getContentPane().add(sp);

    txtrInstructions = new JTextArea();
    sp.setViewportView(txtrInstructions);
    txtrInstructions.setEditable(false);
    txtrInstructions.setText("Welcome to the Retail Operations Application.  For instructions on how to use the program continue reading.\r\n\r\nImportant Information:\r\nIn order to use this application in this version you must input the items contained in the store inventory before you can use the other functions of the program.\r\n\r\nAdd Item to Store:\r\nPressing this button opens the store inventory editor where you can create new items and edit existing ones.  Using this twice will overwrite the previous store inventory created.\r\n\r\nAdd Item to Customer Cart:\r\nPressing this button opens the dialog to add an item to a customer's shopping cart.  Using this feature twice will overwright previous customer cart.\r\n\r\nShow Customer Cart:\r\nPressing this button will display a list of the items currently in the customer's shopping cart and allow for calculation of the total cost of the customer's purchase.\r\n\r\nExit Program:\r\nOnce done, press this button to close the program.");
    txtrInstructions.setRows(10);
    txtrInstructions.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    txtrInstructions.setLineWrap(true);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    btnAIS.addActionListener(handler);
    btnAIC.addActionListener(handler);
    btnSCC.addActionListener(handler);
    btnEProgram.addActionListener(handler);
}

//Creates inner-class which detects events as they are sent and enacts the proper methods associated with those events.
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == btnAIS)
        {
            mOps.guiSInventory();
        }

        else if (event.getSource() == btnAIC)
        {
            mOps.guiCInventory();
        }

        else if (event.getSource() == btnSCC)
        {
            mOps.guiCCheckout();
        }

        else if (event.getSource() == btnEProgram)
        {
            mMenu.dispose();
        }

        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An error has occured: Message, " + event.getActionCommand() + ", cannot be resolved.", "ERROR CODE 8",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }           
    }
}   

//Global References
MenuOperations mOps = new MenuOperations();
JLabel lblTitle; 
JScrollPane sp;

//Main Menu GUI References
JFrame mMenu;
JButton btnAIS;
JButton btnAIC;
JButton btnSCC;
JButton btnEProgram;
JTextArea txtrInstructions; 
}
```

MenuOperations:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class MenuOperations extends JFrame
{

public MenuOperations()
{

}

public void guiSInventory()
{       
    setBounds(100, 100, 537, 390);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    sInv = this;        
    setVisible(true);

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Store Inventory Editor");
    lblTitle.setBounds(10, 0, 169, 14);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(lblTitle);

    sp = new JScrollPane();
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setBounds(10, 161, 501, 180);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(sp);

    sInventory = new JTable();
    tSModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    sInventory.setModel(tSModel);
    tSModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Item Name", "Department", "Item Price", "Item Sale Price"});

    sInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(163);
    sInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(118);
    sInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(95);
    sp.setViewportView(sInventory);

    txtIName = new JTextField();
    txtIName.setText("Item Name");
    txtIName.setBounds(10, 39, 109, 20);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(txtIName);
    txtIName.setColumns(10);

    cbDept = new JComboBox(sDept);
    cbDept.setToolTipText("Choose a Department");
    cbDept.setBounds(157, 39, 133, 20);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(cbDept);

    txtIPrice = new JTextField();
    txtIPrice.setText("Item Price");
    txtIPrice.setBounds(315, 39, 86, 20);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(txtIPrice);
    txtIPrice.setColumns(10);

    txtISPrice = new JTextField();
    txtISPrice.setText("Item Sale Price");
    txtISPrice.setBounds(425, 39, 86, 20);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(txtISPrice);
    txtISPrice.setColumns(10);

    btnAISI = new JButton("Add Item to Inventory",null);
    btnAISI.setBounds(64, 81, 141, 23);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(btnAISI);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit",null);
    btnExit.setBounds(315, 81, 89, 23);
    sInv.getContentPane().add(btnExit); 

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    btnAISI.addActionListener(handler);
    btnExit.addActionListener(handler);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void guiCInventory()
{
    setBounds(100, 100, 537, 339);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    cInv = this;        
    setVisible(true);

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Store Inventory Editor");
    lblTitle.setBounds(10, 0, 169, 14);
    cInv.getContentPane().add(lblTitle);

    sp = new JScrollPane();
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setBounds(10, 161, 501, 180);
    cInv.getContentPane().add(sp);

    cInventory = new JTable();
    tCModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    cInventory.setModel(tSModel);
    tSModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Item Name", "Department", "Item Price", "Item Sale Price"});

    cInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(163);
    cInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(118);
    cInventory.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(95);
    sp.setViewportView(cInventory);

    Object[] oArray = ops.getINames();
    cbItems = new JComboBox(oArray);
    cbItems.setToolTipText("Choose an Item to Add");
    cbItems.setBounds(10, 39, 133, 20);
    cInv.getContentPane().add(cbItems);

    btnAICI = new JButton("Add Item to Inventory",null);
    btnAICI.setBounds(193, 38, 141, 23);
    cInv.getContentPane().add(btnAICI);

    btnExit2 = new JButton("Exit",null);
    btnExit2.setBounds(411, 38, 89, 23);
    cInv.getContentPane().add(btnExit2);    

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    btnAICI.addActionListener(handler);
    btnExit2.addActionListener(handler);
}

public void guiCCheckout()
{

    setBounds(100, 100, 537, 334);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    cCOut = this;       
    setVisible(true);

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Store Inventory Editor");
    lblTitle.setBounds(10, 0, 169, 14);
    cCOut.getContentPane().add(lblTitle);

    sp = new JScrollPane();
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setBounds(10, 161, 501, 180);
    cCOut.getContentPane().add(sp);

    sp.setViewportView(cInventory);     

    btnCBill = new JButton("Calculate Bill",null);
    btnCBill.setBounds(20, 224, 100, 23);
    cCOut.getContentPane().add(btnCBill);

    txtCBill = new JTextField();
    txtCBill.setText("Calculate Bill");
    txtCBill.setBounds(330, 224, 146, 20);
    cCOut.getContentPane().add(txtCBill);
    txtCBill.setColumns(10);

    btnExit3 = new JButton("Exit",null);
    btnExit3.setBounds(183, 262, 89, 23);
    cCOut.getContentPane().add(btnExit3);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    btnCBill.addActionListener(handler);
    btnExit3.addActionListener(handler);
}

//Creates inner-class which detects events as they are sent and enacts the proper methods associated with those events.
    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getSource() == btnAISI)
            {           
                //Convert string to float
                f1 = new Float(txtIPrice.getText());
                f2 = new Float(txtISPrice.getText());   

                if (cbDept.getSelectedItem().equals("Appliances"))
                {
                    s2 = "Appliances";          
                }

                else if (obj == Electronics)
                {
                    s2 = "Electronics";
                }

                else if (obj == bBath)
                {
                    s2 = "Bed/Bath";
                }

                else if (obj == Furnishings)
                {
                    s2 = "Furnishings";
                }

                else if (obj == mClothing)
                {
                    s2 = "Men's Clothing";
                }

                else if (obj == wClothing)
                {
                    s2 = "Women's Clothing";
                }

                else if (obj == Landscaping)
                {
                    s2 = "Landscaping";
                }

                else if (obj == Pet)
                {
                    s2 = "Pet";
                }

                ops.addSItem(txtIName.getText(), s2, f1, f2, sInventory, tSModel);
            }

            else if (event.getSource() == btnAICI)
            {
                //Obtain department name
                s1 = (String)cbItems.getSelectedItem();

                ops.addCItem(s1, cInventory, tCModel);
            }

            else if (event.getSource() == btnCBill)
            {
                cTotal = ops.cCBill();

                String.format("%.2f", cTotal) ;

                txtCBill.setText(cTotal.toString());
            }

            else if (event.getSource() == btnExit)
            {
                sInv.dispose();
            }

            else if (event.getSource() ==  btnExit2)
            {
                ops.clearINames();
                cInv.dispose();
            }

            else if (event.getSource() == btnExit3)
            {
                cCOut.dispose();
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An error has occured: Message, " + event.getActionCommand() + ", cannot be resolved.", "ERROR CODE 8",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }


//Global References
    Operations ops = new Operations();
    JLabel lblTitle; 
    JScrollPane sp;
    JTextField  txtIName;
    static String[] sDept = {"Appliances","Electronics","Bed/Bath","Furnishings","Men's Clothing","Woman's Clothing","Landscaping","Pet"};
    JTextField  txtIPrice;
    JTextField  txtISPrice;

    //Store Inventory GUI References/Variables
    JFrame      sInv;
    JButton btnAISI;
    JButton btnExit;
    JTable      sInventory;
    JComboBox   cbDept;
    DefaultTableModel tSModel;

    //Customer Inventory GUI References/Variables
    JFrame      cInv;
    JButton     btnAICI;
    JButton     btnExit2;
    JTable      cInventory;
    JComboBox   cbItems;
    DefaultTableModel tCModel;

    //Customer Checkout GUI References
    JFrame cCOut;
    JButton btnCBill;
    JTextField txtCBill;
    JButton btnExit3;


    //btnASIS event method Variables
    Float f1,f2,cTotal;
    Object obj,Appliances,Electronics,bBath,Furnishings,mClothing,wClothing,Landscaping,Pet;
    String s1,s2;


}
```

Operations:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class Operations
{
public Operations()
{
    //Create Array Lists
    sItems = new ArrayList<TableValues>();
    cItems = new ArrayList<TableValues>();      
}

public void addSItem(String s1, String s2, float f1, float f2, JTable table, DefaultTableModel model)
{
    for (i = 0;;i++)
    {
        if (table.getRowCount() < 0)
        {
            if (table.getModel().getValueAt(i,0).equals(s1))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item already exists!","Program Information",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }           

            else if (i == table.getRowCount())
            {
                sItems.add(new TableValues(s1, s2, f1, f2));
                updateSTable(table, model);
                break;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            sItems.add(new TableValues(s1, s2, f1, f2));
            updateSTable(table, model);
            break;              
        }
    }
}

public void addCItem(String s1, JTable table, DefaultTableModel model)
{
    for (i = 0; i < table.getRowCount()-1; i++)
    {       
        if (sItems.get(i).getIName().equals(s1))
        {
            s2 = sItems.get(i).getDName();
            f1 = sItems.get(i).getIPrice();
            f2 = sItems.get(i).getISPrice();

            cItems.add(new TableValues(s1, s2, f1, f2));
            updateSTable(table, model);
            break;
        }

        else if (i == table.getRowCount() - 1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item Does Not Exist!","Error Code 1",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void updateSTable(JTable table, DefaultTableModel model)
{
    table.removeAll();

    for (TableValues items : sItems)
    {
        f1 = items.getIPrice();
        f2 = items.getISPrice();

        s1 = "" +f1;
        s2 = "" +f2;            

        model.addRow(new String[] {items.getIName(), items.getDName(), s1, s2});
    }

    table.revalidate();
}

public void updateCTable(JTable table, DefaultTableModel model)
{
    table.removeAll();

    for (TableValues items : cItems)
    {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {items.getIName(), items.getDName(), items.getIPrice(), items.getISPrice()});
    }

    table.revalidate();
}

public Object[] getINames()
{
    for (i = 0; i < sItems.size()-1; i++)
    {
        iNames.add(sItems.get(i).getIName());
    }

    return iNames.toArray();
}

public void clearINames()
{
    iNames.clear();
}

public float cCBill()
{
    cTotal = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < cItems.size() -1; i++)
    {
        cTotal += cItems.get(i).getISPrice();
    }

    return cTotal;
}


//Variables
public ArrayList<TableValues> sItems; //Store Items
public ArrayList<TableValues> cItems; //Customer Items
public ArrayList<String>      iNames; //Item Names for combobox
String s1,s2;
float f1,f2,cTotal;
int i;
}
```

TableValues:

```
public class TableValues
{
public TableValues(String name, String depart, float price1, float price2)
{
    tvIName = name;
    tvDepartment = depart;
    tvIPrice = price1;
    tvISPrice = price2;
}

public String getIName()
{
    return tvIName;
}

public String getDName()
{
    return tvDepartment;
}

public float getIPrice()
{
    return tvIPrice;
}

public float getISPrice()
{
    return tvISPrice;
}

//Variables
public String    tvIName; //Item name
public String    tvDepartment; //Department name
public float         tvIPrice; //Item price
public float         tvISPrice; //Item sale price
}
```

Here is the full error message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Operations.getINames(Operations.java:106)
>       at MenuOperations.guiCInventory(MenuOperations.java:109)
>       at GUI$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(GUI.java:69)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Edit 1:

I have fixed it albeit in a bit of a jerry-rigged method.

the getINames method is now written like this:

```
public String getIName(int i)
{
    return sItems.get(i).tvIName;
}
```

And the ComboBox block in guiCInventory is now like this:

```
String[] sArray = new String[ops.getSISize()];

    for (int i = 0; i < ops.getSISize(); i++)
    {
        sArray[i] = ops.getIName(i);
    }

    cbItems = new JComboBox(sArray);
```

Now I just have to get the cInventory table working and I should be done.   Thanks for the suggestions below, they got me to the point I am at.

Comment: Note that it is very confusing to have your class fields declared at the bottom of the class. (They are also not known as variables).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Operations()
{
    //Create Array Lists
    sItems = new ArrayList<TableValues>();
    cItems = new ArrayList<TableValues>();      
}
```

Can you also initialize iNames here and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not initialized your `iNames` declared as(`public ArrayList<String> iNames;`)

You are not instantiating the `iNames` you are directly calling `add` on it. Try adding the line

`iNames = new ArrayList<String>();` in your `getINames()` method as I have added below:

```
public Object[] getINames()
{
    iNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (i = 0; i < sItems.size()-1; i++)
    {
        iNames.add(sItems.get(i).getIName());
    }

    return iNames.toArray();
}
```

Comment: iNames gets initialized in the following method: Operations::addSItem().  That method should be called first in order to add objects to the sItems ArrayList.  Then in getINames the code grabs the tvIName string from the sItems ArrayList objects and places them into iNames.  I will try setting a default object though and see what happens.

Comment: No, it did not keep it from erroring after guiCInventory is called and the ComboBox is created.  It did temporarily keep it from happening though, I found another error with the TableModel which I fixed but then after rerunning it finally loaded the new JFrame but still gave the nullpointerexceiption and stopped loading the JFrame.

Comment: On my first comment I posted the wrong thing, iNames is initialized in the getINames method by pulling the information from the sItems ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

please update your constructor like:

 

`public Operations()
{
    //Create Array Lists
    sItems = new ArrayList();
    cItems = new ArrayList();

    iNames =   new ArrayList() ;
}`

Comment: I attempted that but it still errors out but I have since fixed it.  What I had to do was change how I was getting the data.  So instead of passing all of the names from the Operations class I only pass one element of sItems at a time using an int parameter to iterate through the ArrayList.  In the guiCInventory I replaced what I have above with a String array intilized to the same number of elements of sItems via an int return from Operations.  From there it goes through a for loop and calls the altered getIName method and then sets the String into the sArray in guiCInventory.  Got rid do err